# Arithmetic conversion VS integral promotion

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

```
char cval;
short sval;
long lval;
sval + cval; // sval and cval promoted to int
cval + lval; // cval converted to long
```

This is a piece of code on C++ Primer.
I know `sval+cval` generates an int type according to

> convert the small integral types to a larger integral type. The types
>   bool, char, signed char, unsigned char, short, and unsigned short are
>   promoted to int if all possible values of that type fit in an int.

But for the last one I couldn't understand why it uses "converted". Why is `cval` not promoted to `int` first and then the `int` converted (or maybe promoted I'm not sure whether promoted can be used from `int` to `long` because I only see definition of promotion on smaller type to `int`) to `long`. I didn't see any explanation or examples on `char` straightly to `long` in that part of the book.  
 Is there any thing wrong with my understanding?  
I'm quite new at C++, someone please enlighten me! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additive operators perform what is called the [usual arithmetic conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) on their operands which can include integral promotions and then after that we can have further conversions. The purpose is to yield a common type and if the promotions do not accomplish that then a further conversion is required.

This is covered in section `5` *[expr]* of the draft C++ standard which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield
>   result types in a similar way. **The purpose is to yield a common type**, which is also the type of the result.
>   This pattern is **called the usual arithmetic conversions**, which are defined as follow

and includes the following bullet:

> - **Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed** on both operands.61 Then the following
>     rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:

which has the following bullets:

> - If both operands **have the same type, no further conversion is needed**
> - Otherwise, if **both operands have signed integer types** or both have unsigned integer types, the
>     operand with the **type of lesser integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the
>     operand with greater rank**.
> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the
>     rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
> - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of
>     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall
>     be converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> - Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the
>     type of the operand with signed integer type.

So in the first case after promotions they both have the same type(*int*) so no further conversion is needed.

In the second case after promotions they do not(*int and long*) so a further conversion is required.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts!

Answer (score 0):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **4 Standard conversions**
>
> 1 Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such
>   conversions. A standard conversion sequence is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and boolean conversions.
>
> — Zero or one qualification conversion.

In the expression,

```
cval + lval;
```

since `cval` is not of type `long`, it has to be converted to `long`. However, in the process of applying the standard conversions, *integral promotion* comes ahead of *conversions*. Hence, `cval` is promoted to an `int` first before being converted to a `long`.