# Why does bitwise left shift promotes an uint8_t to a wider type

Tags: c++, bit-shift, uint8t, integer-promotion

I was a bit messing around with `uint8_t` and was curious what happens when I outflow bits to the left and found that

```cpp
uint8_t i = 234;

uint8_t j = (i << 1);
auto    k = (i << 1);

std::cout << (int)j << std::endl;

std::cout << k << std::endl;
```

prints out

```
212
468
```

and not the expected

```
212
212
```

It seems like `<<` does promote an `uint8_t` too some wider integer type. Why does it do this?

[Here](https://tio.run/##Zcw7DsIwDADQOT6FJZZkAInPgNrQq6AoicD9pBV1JsTZg8tSAV5sP3/8NG1v3peyoeT7HCJaGmd@RDc0sNrMgRLv7g2AZBwcJW3wCSpLe74yEl7wcDzVsFIrpAmtxb2pQbnMI0p0XwxKXleVHzMvpOXWtEv14ZhC/7fT/YxfpbwB) a link where you see it in action

Comment: It seems you can do hardly anything to a `uint8_t` without having it promoted to `int`.

Comment: Similar question for [tag:c]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203015/integer-promotion-with-the-operator. I think it would be the same in C++

Comment: Because the standard say so... For some micro controller, you have have an option to disable such promotion for better efficiency (and not be conformant to specifications.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I disagree - you can do _more_ with it than you can with an `int`! ;)

Comment: [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/995714), [Is char default-promoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11985774/995714), [Why does C/C++ automatically convert char/wchar_t/short/bool/enum types to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20747614/995714), [Is promotion to int required by the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23635240/995714)

Comment: One of the reason might be related to the fact that if you do something like `auto x = 20 * 30;`, you probably expect 600 and not 88 (or -168) as 8 bit number would easily overflow.

Comment: The cppreference article about [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

Comment: @Phil1970 Both `20` and `30` are `int`, not "8 bit number"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty much every arithmetic operation performs what's called the *usual arithmetic conversions*.

This goes back decades.

First, integral promotions are performed.

- No arithmetic operation takes `uint8_t` so both of your operands will always be promoted.

After that, a common type is found and conversions take place if necessary.

- You can prevent this by casting the right-hand-side to the type of `i` but, per the above rule, that doesn't get you anything in this case.

*(You can learn more about this process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486987/560648) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions).)*

The upshot is that the result of your expression is never going to be `uint8_t`; it's just that in the case of `j` you've cast it *back* to `uint8_t`, with the wraparound that consequently ensues.

Comment: More precisely it would be said usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: that does not seem to solve the problem [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc07DsIwDAbguTmFJZZkAInHgNrQq6AoicB9JBVxJsTZg8sSAV4sf78t22XZ3qwtZYPBTtl50BgTPbyZe1EtkcNAu3svBHeYDQap4CmazOP5SoBwgcPx1FVJLPtOVBgYJILWkBTvmUwRuMYvFg2/alsbM60k@VYNn3BlH9z0tzP@xK9S3g "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Ackdari Oh, true - okay see edit